# Render components via window.location.pathname

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render different components via an if-statement, that depends on the path name. See return statement below.

```
return (
    <>  
      <Navbar style={{position:"sticky"}} ammount={safedIds.length} setShowCalendar={setShowCalendar} />
      <DateBar date={currentDate? currentDate:"no date available"} />
      {eventsPrep.length > 0 ? 
        window.location.pathname === "/calendar"?
        <Calendar />
        :
        <Home events={eventsPrep} addSafedId={addSafedId} />
      : <></>}
    </>
    
  );
```

I know that the path updates but the components do not.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It maybe better to use a router library.

Comment: For example, [react-location](https://react-location.tanstack.com/) or [react-router](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router).